# In pyqt, is there a way to signal a secondary thread(QThread) to raise an exception

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pyqt, qthread

My run function in the Secondary Thread looks like this:

```
def run(self):
    try:
        self.TestScript()
    except  Exception,  e:
        //Bunch of clean up code...
```

This is normally great because any exception allows the system to be cleaned up and put in a safe state.  I want to add an Abort Button in the Primary Thread that raises an exception in the Secondary Thread.   I tried to create method in the QThread object that raises an exception, but it's the Primary Thread that raises the exception when the signal is fired.

Anybody know if the QThread can be signaled to raise an exception in it's own thread asynchronously?

Comment: I went back to my older Python scripts I wrote and noticed that Python threads has a interrupt_main() method that raises a KeyboardInterrupt exception in the thread.  Anybody know if I can simulate the same behavior with a QThread?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads). I think you're after the [Qt.QueuedConnection](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) type that you should pass as an argument to `connect`.